# How to accept clients in a generic way (tcp / pipe ) with libuv?

Tags: c, libuv

I would like to have a generic `on_connection` callback that works with any type of server stream (pipe or tcp), but to accept the connection, you should provide an initialized client...

However `uv_stream_t` is an abstract struct.

Is there an official way to do that ?
Else, can I do a switch relying on the private and undocumented `uv_hundle_t.type` member ?

Or should I use my own way of knowing the type using the `.data` pointer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uv_handle_t.type, it's not "private".  I just realized we haven't documented it, so I created [an issue](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1044).

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I guess my eyes were tired when I looked in the header :/